# THREEJS - Mesh disappears after loading image

Tags: vue.js, three.js

I want to add an image to my Sphere. I have looked up so many versions of loading an image but it seams like my version should be correct. After commenting out `map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('earth.jpg'),`, the sphere is visible but when trying to load the image, it disappears.

```
this.sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radius, this.segments, this.segments),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
          map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('earth.jpg'),
          side: THREE.BackSide
        }))
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Please demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/kf8mdz1c/).

Comment: If you can share your full code then we can help. There are no issues with the code you shared.